# Difficulty uploading a file to a FileField, form isn't valid

Tags: django, file-upload, python-3.5, django-1.11

Halo, i'm trying to upload a file using filefield. But i always failed. when statement `form.errors.as_data()` executed, the browser return 'tempfile'. I already trying to find solution from django documentation and some django references. But, still can't fix it. ;(

Here's my view.py

```
def dataprocessing(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
       import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
       newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['myfile'])
       newdoc.save()

       #Redirect to the dataprocessing after POST
       #return render(request, 'dataprocessing.html')
       return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
       return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_data())

else:
     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
     form = DocumentForm() #A empty, unbound form

return render(request, 'dataprocessing.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
class Document(models.Model):
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
tempfile = forms.FileField()
```

And dataprocessing.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url "dataprocessing" %}">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="up">Input Data</label> {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file" name=myfile class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-buttonBefore="true" data-size="sm" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                            id="up">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Upload Data</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Download Template</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Please choose a more appropriate title for your question.

Comment: Your template isn't uploading a file for the field `tempfile` but for `myfile` (well that should be a string: `<input name="tempfile" .../>`)

Comment: Try to learn to use debugging tools so that you can inspect what is actually posted, makes it much easier to solve these kind of issue. E.g. use a `pdb` line in your code to set a breakpoint, or use django-debugger to inspect the request.

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman

Comment: @dirkgroten yuup. I'll try to debug it again. Thank you sir

Comment: If you want to save yourself a lot of problems, try using form rendering in your templates, so that you're sure your HTML inputs have the correct attribute for your form: e.g. `{{ form.tempfile }}` to render the `<input>` field for your `tempfile` field. If you need to add attributes, do that by adding them to the widget, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `forms.ModelForm` instaed `forms.Form` like this?

```
# forms.py
class DocumentForm(forms.Model):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ['tempfile']
```

and make your `views.py` like this:

```
# views.py
def dataprocessing(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("success")
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors.as_data())
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() #A empty, unbound form
    return render(request, 'dataprocessing.html', {'form': form})
```

This makes `form` object can be saved directly to your model.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying your solution, and raise this `Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form DocumentForm needs updating.`

So it means that we have to create at least 1 field ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot it. you can simply use `fields = ['tempfile']`

Comment: Answer Updated!

Comment: The problem I think is in his HTML form, not in the form back-end. Using a `ModelForm` is indeed easier and the recommended way to go in this case, but doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: If you think form is problem, how about using `{{ form.as_p }}` in your HTML?

Comment: Thank you @Beomi. I follow your suggestion, and it fix the problem. I also change my model.py to 
`class Document(models.Model):
#the variable to take the inputs
    tempfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')`

And recheck the html. ;)

Comment: My mistake was not including request.FILES; few books mention this detail. Thanks for you example!